# Building audio analysis library Essentia failed with Gaia support

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying to build `Essentia` (https://github.com/MTG/essentia), an audio analysis library, with `Gaia` (https://github.com/MTG/gaia) support in `Debian 9.0` from source. Before that, one of its dependencies, namely `Gaia`, was successfully  built, also, from source. It was installed in `/usr/local/`.

When it comes to `Essentia`, compilation of sources fails with the following errors:

```
[...]
        In file included from ../src/algorithms/essentia_algorithms_reg.cpp:21:0:
    ../src/algorithms/highlevel/gaiatransform.h: At global scope:
    ../src/algorithms/highlevel/gaiatransform.h:37:10: error: ‘TransfoChain’ in namespace ‘gaia2’ does not name a type
       gaia2::TransfoChain _history;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    ../src/algorithms/highlevel/gaiatransform.h: In constructor ‘essentia::standard::GaiaTransform::GaiaTransform()’:
    ../src/algorithms/highlevel/gaiatransform.h:47:5: error: ‘init’ is not a member of ‘gaia2’
         gaia2::init();
         ^~~~~
    ../src/algorithms/highlevel/gaiatransform.h:47:5: note: suggested alternative:
    In file included from ../src/essentia/algorithmfactory.h:27:0,
                     from ../src/algorithms/essentia_algorithms_reg.cpp:1:
    ../src/essentia/essentia.h:46:6: note:   ‘essentia::init’
     void init();
          ^~~~
```

The file where the error lies is `/src/algorithms/essentia_algorithms_reg.cpp` and here is the command which the file is compiled with:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -pipe -Wall -std=c++03 -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -O2 -fPIC -pthread -Isrc -I../src -Isrc/essentia -I../src/essentia -Isrc/essentia/scheduler -I../src/essentia/scheduler -Isrc/essentia/streaming -I../src/essentia/streaming -Isrc/essentia/streaming/algorithms -I../src/essentia/streaming/algorithms -Isrc/essentia/utils -I../src/essentia/utils -Isrc/3rdparty -I../src/3rdparty -Isrc/3rdparty/spline -I../src/3rdparty/spline -Isrc/3rdparty/vamp-plugin-sdk-2.4 -I../src/3rdparty/vamp-plugin-sdk-2.4 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/taglib -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/local/include/gaia2/ -DHAVE_AVCODEC=1 -DHAVE_AVFORMAT=1 -DHAVE_AVUTIL=1 -DHAVE_AVRESAMPLE=1 -DHAVE_SAMPLERATE=1 -DHAVE_TAGLIB=1 -DHAVE_YAML=1 -DHAVE_FFTW=1 -DHAVE_GAIA2=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -DPYTHONDIR="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages" -DPYTHONARCHDIR="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages" -DHAVE_PYEMBED=1 -DHAVE_PYEXT=1 -DHAVE_PYTHON_H=1 ../src/algorithms/essentia_algorithms_reg.cpp -c -o/home/hamidi/essentia/build/src/algorithms/essentia_algorithms_reg.cpp.1.o -fPIC -v
```

`g++`'s `-v` option gave me the actual paths visited by the linker (nothing bad in there, I think, but for the sake of completeness):

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 src
 ../src
 src/essentia
 ../src/essentia
 src/essentia/scheduler
 ../src/essentia/scheduler
 src/essentia/streaming
 ../src/essentia/streaming
 src/essentia/streaming/algorithms
 ../src/essentia/streaming/algorithms
 src/essentia/utils
 ../src/essentia/utils
 src/3rdparty
 ../src/3rdparty
 src/3rdparty/spline
 ../src/3rdparty/spline
 src/3rdparty/vamp-plugin-sdk-2.4
 ../src/3rdparty/vamp-plugin-sdk-2.4
 /usr/include/taglib
 /usr/include/qt4
 /usr/include/qt4/QtCore
 /usr/local/include/gaia2/
 /usr/include/c++/6
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6
 /usr/include/c++/6/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

Here are the files (github repo) involved in the error:

- MTG/gaia/blob/master/src/gaia.h
- MTG/gaia/blob/master/src/transformation.h#L106
- /MTG/essentia/blob/master/src/algorithms/highlevel/gaiatransform.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is finally an error that occurred while configuring `Gaia` that caused the problem. Actually, rather than using merely the following options for configuration:

```
./waf configure --with-python-bindings --with-asserts --with-cyclops
```

the option `--with-stlfacade` was added by inadvertence. This option  is not compatible when using `Gaia` in conjunction with `Essentia`.